# Is there any study in the science about these true stories of babies?

Tags: psychology, children

For babies from several-month old to 4-year old, most of them get their parents frustrated(e.g. most babies often cry). But I heard of true stories of several babies. These true stories have the following common or similar parts about such babies:

1. After being left alone, such babies usually don't cry. He/She can play with himself/herself quietly for several hours.
2. When introduced by parents to a stranger, most babies are shy and even cry if they are taken in the stranger's arms. But, unlike most babies, such babies usually don't shy, and don't cry in the stranger's arms. Such babies do what parents tell them to do (e.g. say hello or wave hands to the stranger), and even smile to the stranger.
3. Such babies usually do what parents tell them to do. For example, most babies cry when they are given an injection by a doctor. But, unlike most babies, such babies usually stop crying after parents just coax them with only a few words.

Honestly, I'm not sure about the following things:

- I'm not sure whether such babies have more common/similar stories.
- I'm not sure whether these stories or similar stories are sufficiently common. (I'm trying to collect more true stories or similar stories, if any, and post them here later).

I'm interested in the following topics:

- Do such babies have any common/similar stories when they reach adolescence (or adulthood)?
- If above stories are sufficiently common, then what are the factors behind these stories?
- If above stories are sufficiently common, are there any special terms or phrases for describing such babies?

**My question is: Is there any study in the science (e.g. Psychology, Pediatrics, Medicine, and etc) about above true stories of such babies?**
It would be better, if there is any study on my interested topics mentioned above.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  It looks to me like you took 3 arbitrary characteristics, and asked if there is a name for this random combination.  If you are implying that this combination is sufficiently common that it might have a name, then please provide evidence that it is "a real thing in the world" and not just something you made up.  There are also too many questions here (please limit to 1 per post), so closing for that reason.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg, Thanks for your suggestions.I limited it to one question.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg, You mentioned that "please provide evidence that it is 'a real thing in the world' and not just something you made up." On the one hand, the story of one of such babies mentioned in this post happened decades ago. The story of another one of such babies mentioned in this post happened years ago when I heard of it from a chat with other people. I'm sorry that I can't get the Real-world evidence (RWE) of these two cases. On the other hand, I'm tring to collect similar stories on the internet, and hope people who provide a story can also provide a RWE of that story.

Comment: @yo-yos This isn't a good site to collect anecdotes on, and we ask that questions be based on something more than anecdote/personal observation. I know that can be frustrating when you're trying to look for evidence that a phenomenon exists, but it helps us keep the site clear of people asking about all their personal psychology theories, which as a group are usually not answerable or useful questions. Rather than discriminate against particular questions, we have developed rules about framing questions with prior research that apply to all questions asked.